# Grunt serve, make root a subfolder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, virtualhost

Is it possible to make the root of grunt serve be a subfolder.

Instead of localhost:9000 is the root, I want `localhost:9000/wz27` to be the root.

This is to make the page behave just like it will when it is published online.

Comment: I read the documentation and it seems not :(

Comment: Ok, not much to do then I guess.

Comment: Why not simply put project's content into subfolder, e.g. `public/wz27`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [grunt-contrib-connect](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect) where you are able to define an option **base**, which is

> The base (or root) directory from which files will be served. Defaults
>   to the project Gruntfile's directory.

eg:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  connect: {
    server: {
      options: {
        base: 'wz27'
        port: 9000
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I ended up moving my files to a subdirectory under App called wz27 and changed `base:` as you said. Thanks.